# AWS Cognito and custom roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS...
We have a home grown user authentication and authorization. 
We define authorizations(roles) in company terms, role1 allows you to do tasks1 and tasks2. Role2 allows one to perform tasks3 only.

I can see how I can use Cognito for my user/password management.
Unclear if I use cognito for roles verification, i.e authorization.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Cognito User Pool one can define both Users and Groups, which can be leveraged to drive fine-grained RBAC permissioning.  You can define a custom attribute in the User model (e.g., "department" or "role") and map this attribute to Groups.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html

Each group can optionally be associated with an IAM role, so it's possible to restrict access to AWS resources (e.g., certain DynamoDB tables) by group -- as an additional layer of security.

However, if you don't need/want to map users to different IAM roles, maybe just handle authentication completely from within your application.

Comment: just to make sure about my understanding, I have custom roles for my problem domain and not concerned about access restriction to AWS resources, would morphing my custom roles into IAM roles gain me anything?

Comment: You'll likely wont gain anything -- and if you require dynamic role definitions (e.g., if you have app functionality letting "admin user" redefine roles within your application) then mapping domain roles closely to IAM roles will just create headaches.   OTOH, if you have distinct user populations, like "customers" vs "customer service agents" and suppose they access different API endpoints, then you can map all customers to one IAM role, all agents to another IAM role, and do coarse-grained permissioning this way -- as a layer in addition to your custom fine-grained authentication.